# React Native, using fetch method, [TypeError: Network request failed]

Tags: react-native, server, fetch, twilio

https://github.com/Karrar14/videoApp/tree/master

That's my project, I'm running the server using `Yarn start` (then I copy the url that's logged and put into the .env file in the root folder) and then running the metro with `npm start`, then opening the .xcworkspace file in the pods to build the app on iPhone 11 and I keep getting this error:  `LOG  error [TypeError: Network request failed]` when I press the connect button in the app.

I've made sure my API credentials are correct.
I learned all this stuff myself, so I'm a beginner, please let me know if you can help.

Comment: I downloaded and ran your app and I did not have a problem making the fetch request. You do need to make sure that you have the correct ngrok URL set in your `.env` file (and if you change the server code, it will restart and create a new tunnel (you might find this article helps you [keep the same ngrok URL when using nodemon](https://philna.sh/blog/2021/03/15/restart-app-not-tunnel-ngrok-nodemon/)). Your repo in GitHub does have you Twilio credentials exposed, so I recommend deleting the API key if you haven't already.

Comment: I see. Did the application function work though? (In terms of the video call). I thought it may be the fetch request, maybe it's something else? Because I'm confident that I have the correct ngrok URL set in the .env

Comment: I didn't get a full video call connected as the token failed (but I assumed that was because you had deleted your token and I hadn't changed that...). I was also using the simulator, and I'm not sure about camera/microphone access within the simulator. Are you able to log from your server to show that the token was successfully generated?